# what is uialertcontroller's default font and font size for its message?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I need to make an attributed string for a uialertcontroller, but I can't find the font or font size that it has be default? I need this to make the message look normal.

Comment: Honest question. Is there one? Or if a user changes the font size via iOS will it change? (I didn't downvote your question - and mine is an honest reply hoping to help you out.)

Comment: Try using the Debug Vide Hierarchy

Comment: *[Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)

Comment: UIAlertControllers do not accept "attributed string" so it is unclear what the question is even about.

Comment: make your own custom alert design if you want to change different font and size

Answer (score 1):

Both screenshots are found in the Debug View Hierarchy on the right panel.

The title font size is 17pt and the font is SFUI-Semibold

[image]

The message would be 13pt and the font is SFUI-Regular

[image]